# open command sh and call new window?

Tags: python

I'm Italian sorry for my english

I created a plugin, working, now I should be assigned to the yellow - blue keys and information (dreambox enigma2 decoder) command
The blue should run a .sh file in the shell and return to the main menu
the same is true for yellow
the info button it should open a skin, a new information menu .. the closure return to the main menu
*the skin (screen) already includes the buttons drawn
I can not understand the error

here's the listing

```
class OpenScript(Screen):
skin = '<screen name="main" position="212,15 etc etc >'
def __init__(self, session, args = 0):  
        Screen.__init__(self, session)


        self.session = session
        try:
            list = listdir('/etc/pandasat/script')
            list = [ x[:-3] for x in list if x.endswith('.sh') ]


        except:
            list = []
                #self['key_blue'] = Label(_('   SpeedTest'))
    #self['key_yellow'] = Label(_('   Update'))
    #self['key_info'] = Label_'   Info'))
    self['version'] = Label(_('Versione %s' % Version))
self['list'] = MenuList(list)
        self['actions'] = ActionMap(['OkCancelActions', 'ColorActions','WizardActions','NumberActions','EPGSelectActions'],{'ok': self.run,
                                                                         #'key_save': self.run,
                                                                          'key_exit': self.close,
                                          'red': self.close,
                                          'green': self.run,
                                          #'info': self.ShowAbout,
                                          #'yellow: self.update,
                                          #'blue': self.speedtest,
                                          'cancel': self.close}, -1)

def run(self):
        script = self['list'].getCurrent()
        if script is not None:
            self.session.open(Console, script.replace('_', ' '), cmdlist=['/script/%s.sh' % script])
        return


#def speedtest(self): ????????

#def update(self): ????? 


#class AboutScreen(Screen):
#   skin = '<screen name="InFo" etc etc etc </screen>'
#
```

Tank' master

Comment: I have to be assigned to the blue / yellow keys and information
commands that I explained above ..
but if such active
'Blue': self.speedtest,
me error .. not definided etc etc ..

Comment: i resolv with   def speedtest(self):
  self.prombt("sh /speedtest.sh")


 def update(self):
  self.prombt("sh //update.sh")

 def prombt(self, com):
  self.session.open(Console,_("start shell com: %s") % (com), ["%s" % com])

Comment: and this ??                       the info button it should open a skin, a new information menu .. the closure return to the main menu *the skin (screen) already includes the buttons drawn I can not understand the error